# No module named 'bge' - scripting without object dependency

Tags: python, scripting

As I already searched through, there are some complications with bge for me, too. I am trying to program a crude chat system and add a loop that breaks once I click the left mouse button.

However, as soon as I add this if-clause and define the mouse controller, it fails running the script.

`import bge
bge.logic.getCurrentController()
Maus=bge.events.LEFTMOUSE
name=input("Willkommen. Namen eingeben und mit Eingabetaste bestätigen. ");
print("Hallo, ich bin %s." % name);
print("Mit linker Maustaste beenden.");
while 1:
    input("<%s> " % name);
    if Maus==true:break;`

(Modified the code after some minor updates)
The console says that the module bge could not be found. As I have no objects in my blender file yet, because I just want to script a chat that is working without any dependency on objects, I am quite helpless.

I am kind of new to python scripting and I did my best but maybe there is an error in the code somewhere. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The `bge` module is part of the [game engine](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/introduction.html), it is only available while the game engine is running. [See this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80050/935) answer.

Comment: Okay, I see that it does not work with the console. I still do not know what to do to make it work? Do I have to go into an other window and start with P or what exactly is needed to be done? Sorry if I don't get it but I cannot find a solution out of the answer you gave there either. (Explaination for noobs or so)

Comment: Operators are used within blender to perform tasks, for example `bpy.ops.object.delete()` will delete the selected objects, they are run each time you choose a menu item or use a shortcut key. Start with the [addon tutorial](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) to see how an operator works. A [modal operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html#modal-execution) is one that allows you to respond to events while it is running, follow the link for an example.